# Сервер для программы

Tags: c#

У меня есть плеер, написанный на C#. Я хочу создать удаленный сервер для того чтобы записывать плейлисты пользователя, для авторизации в приложении и т. д., но я без понятия, как сделать сервер. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Есть два пути, первый - PHP, очень популярный, нацеленный на быстрый результат, можете хоть сейчас зарегистрировать аккаунт на бесплатном хостинге, создать сайт и считайте HTTP-сервер у вас уже есть, ваш плеер сможет с ним общаться через System.Net (самое простое - WebClient), второй - C# ASP.NET, с бесплатными хостингами плохо, придется обойтись экспериментами на localhost, затем купить хостинг или VPS.

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант - Java + Spring + RESTfull. Удобно в том плане, что очень много контента можно найти по разработке и C# с Java более похожи, чем С# с PHP. Либо использовать ASP.NET

Answer (score -2):

Третий путь, использовать Django + Django Rest Framework. Очень просто и быстро можно сделать ваши задачи за пару часов/дней. Плюс админка для управления пользователями, плейлистами и т.д. у вас будет фактически из коробки.